# Cannot install package scikit-learn in Pycharm and through cli on apple m1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip, scipy, pycharm

When it starts, it writes:

```
Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.0.tar.gz (7.2 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... -
```

Then it hangs for an hour and  writes this log (cannot encompass log completely)

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for scipy
Running setup.py clean for scipy
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build numpy scipy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/local/lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in /opt/local/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/local/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /usr/lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in /opt/local/lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in /opt/local/lib
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

File "/private/var/folders/xg/45g_0kp96gj_11cftvnq919r0000gn/T/pip-install-1jwea3es/scikit-learn_dc15d18c3d214b0682eae44ae71e0d21/sklearn/_build_utils/__init__.py", line 35, in _check_cython_version
        raise ModuleNotFoundError(message)
    ModuleNotFoundError: Please install Cython with a version >= 0.28.5 in order to build a scikit-learn from source.
```

I also installed scipy through brew, but it didn't help.

Comment: error shows that it needs C/C++ libraries `lapack` / `blas` which you have to install separatelly. They may need also source code or at least `dev` versions with files `.h` to compile it.

Comment: I installed lapack and blas from pip,  but it didn't help. I didn't understand what you meant by 'they may need dev versions with files `.h` to compile it' (Unfortunately, I'm bad at building c/c++ libraries).

Comment: [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) and [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)  are NOT python module but C/C++ libraries. you probably installed only Python wrapers on C/C++ modules and you still have to install it as any other program. On Linux Ubuntu/Mint you can install it with `apt install liblapack3 libblas3`, on Mac you can try to install it with `homebrew` or you will have to download and install it manually.

Comment: Some Python modules to access C/C++ library has to compile C/C++ code and they need files with extension `.h` which on Linux Ubuntu/Mint you install with `apt install liblapack3-dev libblas3-dev`

Comment: maybe you should use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual) instead of pure Python because Anaconda should have precompiled and tested these modules - see [blas](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/blas) and [lapack](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/lapack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed anaconda from the official site and got the capability to install sklearn.